# Issues Deploying to Polygon Mainnet

Tags: deployment, polygon, contract

I am having issues deploying to the Polygon Mainnet. I can deploy easily to Polygon Testnet but have yet to successfully deploy to mainnet. I have tried using Truffle, Hardhat and Remix without various errors. Most errors are receiving null back in the blocks in truffle or are gas related. I've increased gas and then I'll get the timeouts or null returns when querying block during deployment. I can't even deploy a 20 line tutorial contract.

Is anyone else having issues and is this a known issue. I find nothing on the web to tell me. I can provide additional information but I think this is a Polygon network issue and I'm trying to confirm.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: i have the same problem, did you manage to solve it?

Comment: same problem :(

Answer (score 0):

Manualy Edit the gas fee to higher on the metamask wallet during the deployment and you will be able to deploy smart contract on polygon network.
Metamask gives you options so i chose to use higher priority gas fee and it worked. No more issues

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).